# Datetime in the format "M1,D1,H1" (January 1st, 1.00 am)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want a column in a dataframe including datetime in the format "M1,D1,H1" (January 1st, 1.00 am). I have a dataframe of the size with 8760 elements. How do I populate it?

Comment: You need to provide some sample data. What is the original format of the dates? Is it already a `datetime64[ns]` or just a string?

Comment: There is no column with datetime information. I have some solar resource data for the entire year at 1 hour resolution and want to add a new column with the mentioned format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.insert(0, 'time', [dt.datetime(self.MODEL_YEAR, 1, 1, 0) + dt.timedelta(hours=int(x))
                                      for x in df['hour'].values])

Answer (score 1):

#### `strftime`

See http://strftime.org/

```
s = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-12-31', freq='400H').to_series()
s.dt.strftime('%B %d, %I %p')

2012-01-01 00:00:00      January 01, 12 AM
2012-01-17 16:00:00      January 17, 04 PM
2012-02-03 08:00:00     February 03, 08 AM
2012-02-20 00:00:00     February 20, 12 AM
2012-03-07 16:00:00        March 07, 04 PM
2012-03-24 08:00:00        March 24, 08 AM
2012-04-10 00:00:00        April 10, 12 AM
2012-04-26 16:00:00        April 26, 04 PM
2012-05-13 08:00:00          May 13, 08 AM
2012-05-30 00:00:00          May 30, 12 AM
2012-06-15 16:00:00         June 15, 04 PM
2012-07-02 08:00:00         July 02, 08 AM
2012-07-19 00:00:00         July 19, 12 AM
2012-08-04 16:00:00       August 04, 04 PM
2012-08-21 08:00:00       August 21, 08 AM
2012-09-07 00:00:00    September 07, 12 AM
2012-09-23 16:00:00    September 23, 04 PM
2012-10-10 08:00:00      October 10, 08 AM
2012-10-27 00:00:00      October 27, 12 AM
2012-11-12 16:00:00     November 12, 04 PM
2012-11-29 08:00:00     November 29, 08 AM
2012-12-16 00:00:00     December 16, 12 AM
Freq: 400H, dtype: object
```